# Cycle through server-side HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, iframe

The company I work for is looking for a way to deploy an effective, minimal administrative overhead, digital signage solution. This means a hidden cursor and a "set it and forget about it" mentality. I already have a Linux box setup with Chrome working in full screen incognito mode. I have a full screen HTML "mainframe" that houses the inner-frame, which pulls HTML pages from our server, displaying each for 20 seconds. A small image is set to load and if the image can't load, such as if the network is down, the frame source changes via JavaScript to a local error page instead of Chrome's built-in terrifying dinosaur (this also only works half of the time, not sure why). I have the following code to cycle through multiple HTML pages on the server to be shown on the screen with a time limit to display each. The issue is, each time we want to add another page to the screen in the display queue, we have to manually go into this code and add another link. I'm not sure how to go about it, but what I would effectively like is for us to just add pages into a directory on the server (say http://server/SIGNAGE1 for screen 1) and have the JavaScript automatically cycle through them changing the frame source (DISPLAY1.html, DISPLAY2.html, DISPLAY3.html, then back to the beginning and repeat). With this solution, the screens wouldn't require administration and the screens would dynamically adjust to how many files it needs to cycle through depending on how many are in the server folder. We have complete control to the naming of the files on the server so they can be numbered consecutively. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Refresher</title>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var Dash = {
 
    nextIndex: 0,

    dashboards: [
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  
  //FORMAT: "{URL: "URL_OF_PAGE", time: TIME_IN_SECONDS_TO_DISPLAY},"
  //AFTER TIME IN SECONDS IS UP, MOVE TO NEXT LINE
  
  //-------------------- ONLY CHANGE BELOW LINES --------------------
  
                {url: "http://server/INSERTHTML1HERE", time: 20},
  {url: "http://server/INSERTHTML2HERE", time: 20},
  {url: "http://server/INSERTHTML3HERE", time: 20},
  
  //-------------------- ONLY CHANGE ABOVE LINES --------------------
  {url: "about:blank", time: 0.1}
    ],

    display: function()
    {
        var dashboard = Dash.dashboards[Dash.nextIndex];
  if (Dash.nextIndex >= (Dash.dashboards.length - 1)) {
   location.reload();
  }
  
  frames["displayArea"].location.href = dashboard.url + "?key=value&ie=" + (new Date()).getTime();
  var errorimage = new Image();
        errorimage.src = 'http://server/errorpages/images/1x1.png?key=value&ie=' + (new Date()).getTime();
  errorimage.onerror = function() {
   frames["displayArea"].location.href = null;
   frames["displayArea"].location.href = 'localerror.html';
  }
  errorimage = null;
  Dash.nextIndex = (Dash.nextIndex + 1) % Dash.dashboards.length;
        setTimeout(Dash.display, dashboard.time * 1000);
    }
};

window.onload = Dash.display;
</script>
<style>
* { cursor: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="pointer-events: none; position:relative; width:100%; height:100%;">
<iframe name="displayArea" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
  Your browser doesn't support IFrames
</iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use AJAX to get a list of all the files from the server, and update the array from that.

Comment: a different approach is to use a meta redirect inside the slide html to advance it, that way you don't even need JS or an iframe, and you can edit the delay with the content.

Comment: with minimal changes to what you have: you could add a url parameter with the number of pages you have and scroll that number of pages, using the number to generate the string of the url.

Comment: I'm currently researching on the solution that Barmar proposed. Dandavis, your suggestion is great, but I am unable to easily edit to content as it is dynamically generated from an Excel spreadsheet that I do not have access to. Julien, your suggestion is great as well, although that would require me to update the client side HTML depending on the number of files on the server at any given time. In the meantime, would all of this be better implemented server side, except for the client-side onerror image code?